# How to auto hide message box?

Tags: c#

I want a timer type of property for message boxes. After displaying error, it must disappear without user intervention after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
timer.Interval=5000;
timer.Enabled=true;
MessageBox.Show("Should close automatically");
```

Associate the following snippet with the timer's `Tick` eventhandler:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs evt) {
    timer.Enabled=false;
    SendKeys.Send("{ESC}"); // SendWait as alternative
}
```

Comment: +1; this DOES work as a workaround.  My answer was specific to the `MessageBox` class =)

Comment: There are any number of reasons why this is bad - even more so if its a message box that's been opened in the first place and hence it could already have been closed.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with the `MessageBox` class; you have to create your own form that mimics it and add this feature yourself.

Comment: Well, you can do this with Windows API message boxes.  You just have to get hold of the message boxes window handle and then post a WM_CLOSE message once the timer fires.  Make sure that you note the event of the window closing and abandon the timer in that eventuality. You'd just need a bit of P/Invoke. But a better solution is not to use a dialog box as per my answer to this Q.

Comment: I probably should've worded it like "`MessageBox` does not have that feature; you need a workaround".

Answer (score 1):

What about using sendkeys?

Something like this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx

at least to get you started in research.

Answer (score 0):

A message box is the wrong solution.  You need a hint window.

Comment: What's a "hint window"? If its something in forms in windows its new to me - if its something you create then that's far too thin an answer.

Comment: It's too thin an answer if you have to do some work?  I'm thinking of the kind of messages that Windows shows when updates have been updated.  You could very easily show a Window with no chrome and just kill it after 5s, but there must be some standard system component.

Answer (score 0):

If this is on a web page, you can use **javascript or jQuery** for a quite nice effect. This is often referred to as **"fade" animation**. It does use a timer.

With this approach, you wouldn't use an actual alert or MessageBox. You use a `<div>` or some other named HTML element.

You can find the code [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-simple-fade-animation) for what you're doing using javascript.

Or if you're using jQuery, look up `fadeOut`. Here's one [article](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).